# AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'RESTRICT'

Tags: python, django

Both CASCASE and PROTECT are working, but I cannot get RESTRICT to work. I am going through the Mozilla tutorial.

```
book = models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete=models.RESTRICT, null=True)
```

I am getting this error when I try to make migrations

```
AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'RESTRICT'
```

I am running django 3.2.4

Comment: I do not find the tutorial about models.RESTRICT on django web site for django 3.2.Could you show  the document/ tutorial  about it ?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.RESTRICT

Comment: Thanks, I get a new use about foreignkey.
But,in my project,django 3.1, I found the arrtiute, RESTRICT. Could you make sure, the django's version not less than 3.1?(I think about the venv about python )

Comment: Yup I'm running 3.2.4

Comment: I mean,the method check django version or python venv,not right?

Answer (score 1):

it is the **version compatibility** problem

I faced the same problem for django 3.2.4

```
 "AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'RESTRICT'"
```

Solution

-> downgrade django to 3.1.2

```
   pip install django==3.1.2  (if you are using python environment)
```

-> it works perfectly now. I hope this works for you

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are importing models like below

from django.db import models

#remove null=True from your model field definition

Comment: Yes I have: from django.db import models
Removing null=True did not work.

Comment: Check the Django version on you virtual environment

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate your virtual environment before run your command.

```
$ python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

you can activate your virtual environment just run following command on your terminal where you have installed virtual environment and created your virtual environment.

```
$ . your_env_name/bin/activate
```

If you don't have any virtual environment , install and create a virtual environment before run any python command for *django*.